# Ruby str[regex, number] syntax

Tags: ruby, regex

In another thread, I encounter this Ruby expression:

```
str[%r{.*//(.*)}, 1]
```

What kind of syntax is this? What does the number 1 mean?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### It's a Regex Slice with MatchData

Basically, this indexes a string based on a regular expression, and returns the first match group. For example:

```
str = 'http://example.com'
str[%r{.*//(.*)}, 1]
# => "example.com"
```

[String#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-slice) has this to say:

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of str is returned. If a numeric or name parameter follows the regular expression, that component of the MatchData is returned instead. If a String is given, that string is returned if it occurs in str. In both cases, nil is returned if there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the explanation of regex slice in CodeGnome's answer. Here's something about MatchData: `str[%r{.*//(.*)}, 1]` is equivalent to `str.match(%r{.*//(.*)})[1]`, and they both work in the same way. The `[]` version is more clear and shorter.

A MatchData acts as an array and/or hash and may be accessed using the normal indexing techniques.

```
m = /(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.")  # m is a MatchData
# and m is   #<MatchData "HX1138" 1:"H" 2:"X" 3:"113" 4:"8">    in irb
m[0]   # "HX1138"
m[1]   # "H"
m[1..2]    #["H", "X"]
```